# Table in multicols and referencing it

Tags: tables, hyperref, multicol

I want a table inside the `multicols` environment that doesn't have text wrapped around it. I would also like to be able to reference it later with a hyperlink. I'm looking for something that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & a \\
        a & a
    \end{tabular} \\
    Table 1: Need caption and
    label.
\end{center}
\lipsum[2-2]
As you can see in table %\ref{tab:table} (here is a hyperlink to table 1).
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I know abou the `wrapfig` package, however I do not know how to not make the text wrap around the table. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: You don't appear to be using a `table` environment. Is this deliberate?

Comment: Yes, because if the table environment does not work in the multicols environment, and wraptable has text wrapped around it.

Comment: Add the `caption` package to your preamble and use `\captionof{table}{Need caption and label.\label{tab:table}}` instead of `Table 1: Need caption and
    label.`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked just like I intended! Will you post it as an answer or should I do it @leandriis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using the package `caption` and the command `\captionof{table}{caption}`. Here is the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-1]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        a & a \\
        a & a
    \end{tabular} \\
    \captionof{table}{caption}
    \label{tab:table}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2-2]
As you can see in table \ref{tab:table} (here is a hyperlink to table 1).
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This method also works for figures if you replace `\captionof{table}{...}` with `\captionof{figure}{...}`, and use `\includegraphics{image.jpg}` where the table is.

Comment: Off-topic, but important: package `hyperref` had to be (with some exceptions which are not present in your MWE) loaded last.